# How to Add values to 'config' table and 'key_value' table when creating a new field in an existing table

Tags: 8, entities, hooks

I need to write a module that need to handle user related details.

I'm able to create the module and add the necessary database changes in '`users_field_data`' table. By using `db_add_field` in `hook_install()`

```
db_add_field('users_field_data', 'user_office', array(
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'length' => 255,
            'not null' => FALSE,
        ));
```

But one thing I noticed when installing some other standard module from drupal, when a new field is added to the database it saves some values to `'config'` table and `'key_value'`table. But when I install the module it only insert the fields to '`users_field_data`' table.

Is there a way that I add the values to `'config'` table and `'key_value'` table when creating a new field in an existing table.